# Short Circuit in Allen Bradley Micro850 Output Headers

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, plc, short-circuit

[image: Micro850 Output Header]

Unfortunately, I have discovered that the outputs 0 and 1, as indicated by my blue Sharpie marks, have continuity. I have inspected the circuit for hours, and cannot seem to find the source of the short. Could anybody please advise on where the short may be, and how to fix it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: check the rest of the PCB

Comment: The chance that there is an internal short in the 
Terminal block while still looking like that (not melted or burned) is very much close to 0.

Comment: I've had this happen on the 850 myself, root cause was hooking up power on the top terminals (which aren't labeled very well) instead of the correct ones on the bottom. There is no fix except to send in for repair.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely two output transistors have failed short-circuit and you're getting a connection through them via the VAC/DC. If that's the case you'll have continuity to VAC/DC as well.

[image]

*Figure 1. Output connections from [user manual](https://docs.rs-online.com/36a5/0900766b8123c7d2.pdf).*

Comment: I checked, and I do not read continuity between Output 0 VAC/DC. Same with Output 1. Any ideas?

Comment: Post a photo of the top side of the board showing the output switching devices.

Comment: I looked at the board for a while. It turns out, there is a defective MOSFET that needs replacing. I am glad you mentioned the transistors could cause the problem outside of the terminal bus. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.